# Why is the jQuery blur not working jQuery's tag-it library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I am trying to use JQuery's blur with tag-it library, however, it isn't working.

I am not sure why blur isn't working.

I click off the input and nothing happens, I don't get an error.

The alert in the blur doesn't appear.

I have tried using:

```
.on(blur, handler)
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ("#id").blur()
})
```

Neither of them worked.

Here is my code:

```
var id_name = [[],[]];
var selected = true;
$("#Approversdisp").tagit({
    allowSpaces: true,
    autocomplete:{
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 600,
        source: function(request, response){
            $("#divreviewersearch").show();
            $.ajax({
                "url" :"private",
                "type" : "GET",
                "data" : {"name": request.term.trim()},
                "contentType" : "application/json",
                "success" : function(data) {
                    id_name[0] = data[0];
                    id_name[1] = data[1];
                    response(data[0]);
                    $("#divreviewersearch").hide();
                },
                "error" : function(error)
                {
                    alert("error: "+JSON.stringify("There was an error!"));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            selected = false;
            var nameid = ui.item.value;
            var approvers = document.addcontent' . $item_id .'.Approvers.value;
            ui.item.label = ui.item.label.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, "");
            ui.item.value = ui.item.value.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, "");
            document.addcontent' . $item_id .'.Approvers.value = approvers+"|"+id_name[1][id_name[0].indexOf(nameid)];
        },
    }
});
$("#Approversdisp").blur(function() {
    alert("in blur");
    if(selected){
        var input = $("#Approversdisp").val();
        input = input.split(",");
        $("#Approversdisp").tagit("removeTagByLabel", input[input.length-1]);
        alert("please pick the tag from the list.");
    }
    selected = true;

});
```

The expected result is the blur working.

Comment: Could you please address the typos in your second snippet?

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with "tag-it", but some UI plugins function by replacing native elements with their own elements that offer the ability to provide the styling they desired.  Have you verified that when interacting with your elements initialized with tag-it that "#Approversdisp" actually gets focus, and not some other dynamically generated element from the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer you have to use

```
$("#inputid").data("ui-tagit").tagInput.blur()
```